# How can I make the vertical scrollbar stay in viewport while its horizontal content overflows?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a page with lists with seperate headers on top. The amount of lists are dynamic and can overflow horizontally. X-scrolling will scroll the entire page. Verticall scrolling the lists should leave the **headers fixed on top**.

I do not want the y-scrollbar to move right with the width of lists but to be always visible at the right edge of the screen. How can I achieve that? 
The Problem seems to be the x-overflow and the necessary alignment of list and header (among others).

Alternatives I have explored: Flipping the scrollbar to the left side (not ideal). 
Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/planta/1e6bxc4o/56/

```css
.header-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  background: whitesmoke;
  text-align: center;
}

.lists-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  background: whitesmoke;
  text-align: center;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  height: 80%;
  width: 100%;
}

.header {
  min-width: 200px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
}

.list {
  min-width: 200px;
  border-right: 1px solid lightgrey;
  border-bottom: 3px solid orange;
  background: steelblue;
  color: white;
  height: 1000px;
}

.outer {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  position: absolute;
}

.intermediate {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">

  <div class="intermediate">

  <div class="header-wrapper">

    <div class="header">
      <span>Title 1</span>
    </div>

    <div class="header">
      <span>Title 2</span>
    </div>

    <div class="header">
      <span>Title 3</span>
    </div>

    <div class="header">
      <span>Title 4</span>
    </div>

    <div class="header">
      <span>Title 5</span>
    </div>

    <div class="header">
      <span>Title 6</span>
    </div>

    <div class="header">
      <span>Title 7</span>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="lists-wrapper">

    <div class="list">
      content 1
    </div>

    <div class="list">
      content 2
    </div>

    <div class="list">
      content 3
    </div>

    <div class="list">
      content 4
    </div>

    <div class="list">
      content 5
    </div>

    <div class="list">
      content 6
    </div>

    <div class="list">
      content 7
    </div>

  </div>

</div>

</div>
```

Comment: I don't think it's possible. Maybe you can do it with some custom scrollbar plugin  and fix the scrollbar's position to the edge of a screen.

Comment: In `.list-wrapper`, remove the `height:80%`.

Answer (score 0):

1- Change overlow-y value to **visible**, and delete overflow-x attribute.

```
   .list-wrapper {
      overflow-y: visible;
    }
```

2- Then, change overflow-y value to **auto**.

```
 .outer {
      overflow-y: auto;
    }
```

Comment: That won't do since I need the headers ( `Title 1` etc) to be fixed when scrolling vertically.

Comment: Then, put `position:fixed;` to `header-wrapper` class. It should work now.

Comment: Sorry if my explanation wasn't clear or I am missing something. But the scroll logic and alignments of header and content should not change and stay like it is seen in my fiddle. `position: fixed` will break the alignment and x-scroll.